# Make php files hidden from outside world

Tags: php, mysql, apache, security

My php website have multiple php files , some of them are for user interface and some of them are helper files(the files, which communicates through database and each other to return a result). Now I need that user can't execute the helper files from their direct url's.

```
e.g. mydomain.com/login.php   ---------- (Interface file, must be accessible to user)
     mydomain.com/login_handle.php   ----(Healper file, must not be accessible to user)
```

So I need is user can execute and browse mydomain.com/login.php but must ot be able to execute mydomain.com/login_handle.php, while login.php and handle_login.php keep communicate and can access each other. Thanks,

**Edit:** Sorry but I'm using shared hosting and there is **no folder other than public_html**.

Comment: Store them outside of the webroot?

Comment: Would the php files, still be able to communicate with each other?

Comment: Ideally, the only thing that should be stored in webroot is your router; all requests should be directed to the router, and it would be responsible for including code located outside of your webroot.

Comment: Also, files with just class implementations should output nothing when requested and output to the browser, unless your code is a little 'dirty'.

Comment: Either store them outside your webroot, or create an `include` folder that is hidden using your web server configuration.  This probably belongs on Server Fault, as it is not a programming issue.

Comment: Yeah you can say my code is dirty, and I just need that user can't access some of the files by typing url. Is that possible? I've searched a lot but no solution...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first things I would attempt:

1. Move the included files outside of the document root
2. Move the included files inside another folder and protect it using `.htaccess`. Alternatively, rename your include files to end with `.inc` and create a rule based on that.
3. Make sure the included files don't output anything; this is not really secure, but if your file only contains functions, class definitions, etc. without producing any output, it would just show an empty page.

The hackish approach for this can be accomplished by using constants:

index.php

```
<?php

define('MY_CONSTANT', '123');

include('helper.php');
```

helper.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('MY_CONSTANT')) { exit; }

// we were called from another file
// proceed
```

**Edit**

The number 2 approach from above can be done by:

1. Create a folder underneath `public_html`, e.g. `includes/`
2. Move all the files that should be included only into this folder
3. Add the following `.htaccess` inside:

   ```
   <FilesMatch "\.php$">
   Order allow, deny
   Deny from all
   </FilesMatch>
   ```

Comment: Yeah I liked your solution. Thanks,

Comment: But for this to do, I've to write a constant in every line, isn't it? Can there be any htaccess solution for this?

Comment: @user1706482 For that I would recommend moving all the included files into a sub folder first.

Comment: You could also test `realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) != __FILE__`.

Comment: @eggyal Interesting approach :) depending on the path length and number of included files this might cause a measurable slowdown though, not sure.

Comment: The hackish approach seems the good way to go since apache themselves discourages the use of .htaccess for a couple of performance and security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use .htaccess.

Instead of 127.0.0.1 this ip, you need to put your server ip address.

```
<Files login_handle.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Comment: Yes I need something exactly like this. But how to make it work?

Comment: Go to public_html folder, and open .htaccess file, or create if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is exactly what I need. But doing this shows a forbidden error for both type of accesses i.e. I can't login forbidden page comes up means even internal files can't access?

Comment: Did you put instead of 127.0.0.1 as your local server ip? Could to try put / before login_handle.php . like this : /login_handle.php

Comment: putting /, just again let both ser and php scripts to access file.